# Why and how is Postfix automatically reading main.cf file?

Tags: postfix

today I changed TLS cert paths in Postfix main.cf file. Those paths turned out to be broken.

In a few minutes, Postfix has read those changed paths and my TLS connections became broken (becouse of broken paths).

Question 1: Why Postfix automatically reads changes from main.cf file? Is is documented? I can't find any information about it.

Question 2: Can I turn off this behaviour? I expected Postfix to replace certs after reload of the service, not on the fly.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Picking up changes is *by design* standard procedure in most Postfix components.** In fact, many parts of Postfix explicitly permit swapping out running processes for new ones at any point. Many configuration parameters are setup to automatically take effect eventually - with or without manual intervention (`reload`).

> Changes to main.cf are picked up automatically, as  smtpd(8)
> processes run for only a limited amount of time. Use the command "postfix reload" to speed up a change. - [man 8 smtpd](http://www.postfix.org/smtpd.8.html)

If the way you manage your certificates makes such reloads undesirable, you are advised to place your certificates and matching keys together in files that are only changed when such reload operation is safe.

> With Postfix ≥ 3.4 the preferred way to configure server keys and
> certificates is via the "smtpd_tls_chain_files" parameter. - [man 5 postconf](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#smtpd_tls_chain_files)

See the documentation of the `smtpd_tls_chain_files` parameter for additional explanation.

Comment: All clear, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 1):

Most likely Postfix got either restarted or got SIGHUP signal while you were working on the config.

One common cause for daemon restarts/reloads is logrotate: it may restart/reload services so that they re-open their configuration files after log rotation.

It is also possible that Postfix crashed for some other reason and systemd restarted it.

I suggest checking your logs for other events (cron job runs, etc) around the time Postfix went down for you.

Comment: I checked logs, Postfix wasn't restarted or reloaded.
Just after I saved main.cf postfix logged:
"warning: cannot get RSA certificate from file "/path_to_cert": disabling TLS support"